# Factor $(x-3)^2-2(x-3)(y+2)-35(y+2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My train of thought was first to look at it like a perfect square trinomial, but then I saw the $-35$ and had no idea. Can someone put me on the right track please?

Comment: (I) can you factor $t^2 - 2t - 35 \; ?$ (II) can you factor $t^2 - 2 t u - 35 v^2 \; ?$

Comment: Write down the expression for the second one, then substitute $t = x-3$ and $u = y+2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $X=x-3$ and $Y=y+2$ then your expression reduces to 
$$X^2-2XY-35Y^2$$ which equals 
$$X^2-2XY+Y^2-36Y^2
\\=(X-Y)^2-36Y^2\\=(X-Y+6Y)(X-Y-6Y)\\=(X+5Y)(X-7Y)$$

Now substitute the values of $X$ and $Y$ to get the required factors of your given expression.